# Direct effect changes significance and sign when interaction is included

Tags: regression, interaction

I am running a regression analysis where I want to prove a direct effect and a moderator effect.
However, after creating 3 different models, the signs and significance change and I do not really know how to interpret these figures now.

My 1st hypothesis says that A has a positive effect and

my 2nd hypothesis says that B has a negative moderating effect on the effect of A on the outcome.

The 1st hypo seems to be confirmed by model 1. However, when I estimate the full model (model 3), the direct effect of A changes its sign and is not significant anymore. The interaction is significant in model 3 but does not have the sign that I have hypothesized.

My general questions is whether and to what extend both hypotheses are confirmed.

More specific: Can I say that hypo 1 is confirmed by model 1 and hypo 2 is not confirmed because of the wrong sign in model 3 or do I also have to use model 3 to confirm hypo 1?

[image]

Comment: Model 3 coefficients seems like a case of Berkson's Paradox in action to me.

Comment: Any idea, how I can interpret them?

Comment: Look up the paradox. The mediation term is dependent on both variables - when you include it as a separate term, the positive impact of A is already included in and subsumed by the AxB term. You've essentially blown your positivity budget on the interaction, so you have none to spare for its components.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I have looked up the term but I understood that the paradox has something to do with the sample. Furthermore, I am not really a statistic pro. Frankly, I still do not know how to interpret these numbers. Are you saying that I have to do a model without A if I want to text A x B?

It would be nice if you could tell me how you would test hypothesis 1 and 2 if you were me. :)